# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Tags: python, pandas, shap

In Python, I have read in a lightGBM pmml file named `flaml_lgbm.pmml`, like so:

```
from pypmml import Model

model = Model.fromFile('flaml_lgbm.pmml')
```

Then I have tried to generate the SHAP graph with these lines of code:

```
shap_values = shap.KernelExplainer(model).shap_values(X)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X, plot_type="bar")

# positive and negative relationships of the predictors with the target variable
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X)
```

But I get this error:

```
shap_values = shap.KernelExplainer(model).shap_values(X)

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
```

What is wrong with the code, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try to read the documentation for `shap.KernelExplainer`? What does it say should be put between the `()`? Does `model` make sense there? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to include data also in **shap.KernelExplainer()**, try this:

```
shap_values = shap.KernelExplainer(model, X).shap_values(X)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried your code, but now I get this error: TypeError: 'Model' object is not callable

Comment: yes, because you need to pass model.predict() instead of model, I'd advise having a look at the documentation, or some other examples in order to avoid future errors as well :)